# How to get `Cloud Functions shell` work with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Running:

```
firebase experimental:functions:shell
```

When I try to call my function like so:

```
sendEmail('data', {params: 'commentId:12'})
```

I get:

`Info: Function crashed
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'exists' in data`

How does one initiate the new onWrite on a `Firestore` triggered cloud function

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that testing firestore functions locally isn't documented yet, but I assume the problem is that you have to provide the test data in the correct format instead of using a String. Since firestore documents are essentially JSON objects, you could try using something like `sendEmail({test: 'data'}, {params: {commentId:12}})`

Comment: I've tried testing firestore functions many different ways, and they always end in a crash.  I suspect it's not supported yet.  I've brought this up with the Firebase team internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With version [3.15.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.15.1) of the Firebase CLI, you can now [run Firestore functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_firestore_functions).